# Simulate curl command using urllib in Python - httplib.InvalidURL: nonnumeric port:

Tags: python, http-post, urllib2

I am trying to replicate the following `CURL` command in Python (*I am trying to make a `POST` request with some data on a specific IP*):

```
curl -k --data "phonenr=a_number&smstxt=Test&Submit=SendSms" https://admin:pass@ip/txsms.cgi
```

where `ip` is the IP of the remote server and `admin:pass` are the credentials required.

This CURL command executes correctly and the response is `200`.

With the following python code, I receive:

`httplib.InvalidURL: nonnumeric port: 'pass@91.195.144.248'`

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong ?

```
import urllib2 as urllib
from os.path import join as joinPath
from urllib import urlencode

# constant
APPLICATION_PATH = '/srv/sms_alert/'
ALERT_POINT_PATH = joinPath(APPLICATION_PATH, 'alert_contact')
URL_REQUEST_TIMEOUT = 42

SMS_BOX_URL = 'https://admin:pass@ip/txsms.cgi'

with open(ALERT_POINT_PATH, 'r') as alertContactFile:
    for line in alertContactFile:
        line = line.strip('\n')
        data = {
            'phonenr': line,
            'smstext': 'Test',
            'Submit': 'SendSms'
        }
        url_data = urlencode(data)
        url_data = url_data.encode('UTF-8')
        req = urllib.Request(SMS_BOX_URL, url_data)
        with urllib.urlopen(req) as response:
            print(response.read())
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, take a look at your imports, the code should be working fine. The problem is that first you are importing urllib2 as urllib, and the importing urlencode from urllib, so you don't get the function you want.

Look at the following code retrieved from urlib2 docs:

Link: [URLLIB2 documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/urllib2.html%22Urllib2%22)

```
import urllib
import urllib2

url = 'http://www.someserver.com/cgi-bin/register.cgi'
values = {'name' : 'Michael Foord',
          'location' : 'Northampton',
          'language' : 'Python' }

data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the authentication (we will assume that it's basic authentication)  cannot be send like a curl command,  urllib will consider the user as the hostname and what's after the ':' as the port, which is why you have this error,

You will have to try setting an urllib opener with your credentials like this :

```
import urllib2 as urllib
SMS_BOX_URL = 'https://hostname/txsms.cgi'
# Prepare an authentication handler
auth_handler = urllib.HTTPBasicAuthHandler()
# Set your authentication Handler (catch the realm by parsing the authentication request with your navigator
auth_handler.add_password('realm', 'the realm of the authent', 'admin', 'pass')
opener = urllib.build_opener(auth_handler)
# Install your opener for later use
urllib.install_opener(opener)

# use it
url_data = urlencode(data)
url_data = url_data.encode('UTF-8')
req = urllib.Request(SMS_BOX_URL, url_data)
with urllib.urlopen(req) as response:
  print(response.read())
```

This should work,
the opener only need to be instanciated once

[ref](http://kentsjohnson.com/kk/00010.html)

Comment: What should I write instead of: `'realm', 'the realm of the authent'` ?

Comment: you should see it when parsing the server request header,  something like : ``WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="WallyWorld"``. you can try None (without quotes)